# Overide Javascript Alert Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a add to cart button that can be clicked on my site. When that button is clicked a few actions could happen. The default action is to add the item to the cart then show an alert box stating `[#] item(s) added to your cart`. But there are other situations where if a person doesn't choose an option it will also alert them.

What I would like to do is override these alerts and show my own alerts. I have to base what alert to show depending on what text is shown in the alert.

For instance if a person wants to buy an item and they click Add to Cart. The following will be shown: `[#] item(s) added to your cart`. In this care the alert had the `item(s) added to your cart` then I would want to run a certain JS function.

How do I do this?

I found the following code:

```
(function() {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function() {
    // do something here
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

This will let me run a function when an alert box is open but it 1) doesn't prevent the original alert box from showing and 2) I need to run a specific function based on the text of the alert.

Any guidance and assistance in the correct direction is helpful. Examples are welcome as well.

Note: I am using jQuery 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacement function should take an argument, and examine it to do different things based on the text. And to prevent the original alert box from showing, don't call `proxied.apply`.

```
(function() {
    var proxied = window.alert;
    window.alert = function(text) {
        if (text.indexOf("added to your cart")) {
            // do something here
        } else {
            // do normal alert
            return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})();
```